# How to add a mask in a TextField in Flutter?

Tags: dart, textfield, flutter, masking

I'm trying to add a date mask to a textField since I did not like the Date Picker because for date of birth, for example, it is not as nimble.
After that, converting from string to datetime, I believe I can continue the project,
Thanks in advance.

```
static final TextEditingController _birthDate = new TextEditingController();
    new TextFormField( 
            controller: _birthDate, 
            maxLength: 10,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime, 
            validator: _validateDate
        ), String _validateDate(String value) { 
    if(value.isEmpty)
        return null;
    if(value.length != 10)
        return 'Enter date in DD / MM / YYYY format';
    return null; 
}
```

Comment: Did you any try for this? any code??

Comment: code
`static final TextEditingController _birthDate = new TextEditingController();`
`new TextFormField(
             controller: _birthDate,
             maxLength: 10,
             keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime,
             validator: _validateDate,
         ),`

`String _validateDate(String value){
  if(value.isEmpty) return null;
  if(value.length != 10)
    return 'Enter date in DD / MM / YYYY format';
  return null;
}`

however the user is required to use \.
would not it have some way to leave it automatic and disable the keyboard options?

Comment: try with my answer @victor Henrique

Answer (score 10):

I modified some things and managed to get the expected result.

I created this class to define the variable

```
static final _UsNumberTextInputFormatter _birthDate = new _UsNumberTextInputFormatter();

class _UsNumberTextInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
TextEditingValue oldValue,
TextEditingValue newValue  ) {
final int newTextLength = newValue.text.length;
int selectionIndex = newValue.selection.end;
int usedSubstringIndex = 0;
final StringBuffer newText = new StringBuffer();
if (newTextLength >= 3) {
  newText.write(newValue.text.substring(0, usedSubstringIndex = 2) + '/');
  if (newValue.selection.end >= 2)
    selectionIndex ++;
}
if (newTextLength >= 5) {
  newText.write(newValue.text.substring(2, usedSubstringIndex = 4) + '/');
  if (newValue.selection.end >= 4)
    selectionIndex++;
}
if (newTextLength >= 9) {
  newText.write(newValue.text.substring(4, usedSubstringIndex = 8));
  if (newValue.selection.end >= 8)
    selectionIndex++;
}
// Dump the rest.
if (newTextLength >= usedSubstringIndex)
  newText.write(newValue.text.substring(usedSubstringIndex));
return new TextEditingValue(
  text: newText.toString(),
  selection: new TextSelection.collapsed(offset: selectionIndex),
); 
} 
}
```

And finally I added an inputformat to the textfield

```
new TextFormField( 
          maxLength: 10,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime, 
          validator: _validateDate,
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Digite sua data de nascimento',
            labelText: 'Data de Nascimento',
          ),
          inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter> [
                WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                // Fit the validating format.
                _birthDate,
              ]
        ),
```

Now it's all right, thank you

Answer (score 8):

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/masked_text

**masked_text**

A package for masked texts, so if you want a mask for phone, or zip code or any kind of mask, just use it :D

**Getting Started**

It's very simple, it's a Widget as all the other ones.

```
new MaskedTextField
(
    maskedTextFieldController: _textCPFController,
    mask: "xx/xx/xxxx",
    maxLength: 10,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    inputDecoration: new InputDecoration(
    hintText: "Type your birthdate", labelText: "Date"),
);
```

'x' is the normal char that your text will have.

this sample reproduces something like this in the end: `11/02/1995`.

Comment: it is just going into infinite loop that library is unfortunately not working.

Comment: don't use this. here is a better approach using the native TextField widget: https://pub.dev/packages/mask_text_input_formatter

Comment: @RenanCoelho do you update the text manually later on and keep the format?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the flutter package [mask_text_input_formatter](https://pub.dev/packages/mask_text_input_formatter) (with more than 850 likes)

To use it:

```dart
import 'package:mask_text_input_formatter/mask_text_input_formatter.dart';

var maskFormatter = new MaskTextInputFormatter(
  mask: '+# (###) ###-##-##', 
  filter: { "#": RegExp(r'[0-9]') },
  type: MaskAutoCompletionType.lazy
);

// In your build method
TextField(inputFormatters: [maskFormatter])
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
class MaskTextInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  final int maskLength;
  final Map<String, List<int>> separatorBoundries;

  MaskTextInputFormatter({
    String mask = "xx.xx.xx-xxx.xx",
    List<String> separators = const [".", "-"],
  })  : this.separatorBoundries = {
          for (var v in separators)
            v: mask.split("").asMap().entries.where((entry) => entry.value == v).map((e) => e.key).toList()
        },
        this.maskLength = mask.length;

  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    final int newTextLength = newValue.text.length;
    final int oldTextLength = oldValue.text.length;
    // removed char
    if (newTextLength < oldTextLength) return newValue;
    // maximum amount of chars
    if (oldTextLength == maskLength) return oldValue;

    // masking
    final StringBuffer newText = StringBuffer();
    int selectionIndex = newValue.selection.end;

    // extra boundaries check
    final separatorEntry1 = separatorBoundries.entries.firstWhereOrNull((entry) => entry.value.contains(oldTextLength));
    if (separatorEntry1 != null) {
      newText.write(oldValue.text + separatorEntry1.key);
      selectionIndex++;
    } else {
      newText.write(oldValue.text);
    }
    // write the char
    newText.write(newValue.text[newValue.text.length - 1]);

    return TextEditingValue(
      text: newText.toString(),
      selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: selectionIndex),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution checks when date is out of range (eg. there is not month like 13). It's super inefficient, but it works.

---

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class DateFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  final String mask = 'xx-xx-xxxx';
  final String separator = '-';

  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
 if(newValue.text.length > 0) {
  if(newValue.text.length > oldValue.text.length) {
    String lastEnteredChar = newValue.text.substring(newValue.text.length-1);
    if(!_isNumeric(lastEnteredChar)) return oldValue;

    if(newValue.text.length > mask.length) return oldValue;
    if(newValue.text.length < mask.length && mask[newValue.text.length - 1] == separator) {

      String value = _validateValue(oldValue.text);
      print(value);

      return TextEditingValue(
        text: '$value$separator$lastEnteredChar',
        selection: TextSelection.collapsed(
          offset: newValue.selection.end + 1,
        ),
      );
    }

    if(newValue.text.length == mask.length) {
      return TextEditingValue(
        text: '${_validateValue(newValue.text)}',
        selection: TextSelection.collapsed(
          offset: newValue.selection.end,
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
return newValue;
}

bool _isNumeric(String s) {
if(s == null) return false;
return double.parse(s, (e) => null) != null;
}

 String _validateValue(String s) {
String result = s;

if (s.length < 4) { // days
  int num = int.parse(s.substring(s.length-2));
  String raw = s.substring(0, s.length-2);
  if (num == 0) {
    result = raw + '01';
  } else if (num > 31) {
    result = raw + '31';
  } else {
    result = s;
  }
} else if (s.length < 7) { // month
  int num = int.parse(s.substring(s.length-2));
  String raw  = s.substring(0, s.length-2);
  if (num == 0) {
    result = raw + '01';
  } else if (num > 12) {
    result = raw + '12';
  } else {
    result = s;
  }
} else { // year
  int num = int.parse(s.substring(s.length-4));
  String raw  = s.substring(0, s.length-4);
  if (num < 1950) {
    result = raw + '1950';
  } else if (num > 2006) {
    result = raw + '2006';
  } else {
    result = s;
  }
}

print(result);
return result;
}

}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can now use the boolean property, "obscureText" of TextField to mask input.

Comment: Not related to the question. Asker wants masking the input, not hiding it with * or another character.