# How to only obscure certain text in TextField

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to obscure a social security number while the user enters the text and would like to format to be like `***-**-****` with dashes inserted automatically and bullets obscuring the users numeric entry. Below is the code I'm using, which uses the mask_text_input_formatter package. It almost works, except I'm getting `***********`. Is there a simple way to not obscure the dashes?

```
TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: 'XXX-XX-XXXX',
    ),
    controller: _textController,
    obscureText: true,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    inputFormatters: [MaskTextInputFormatter(mask: '###-##-####')],
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package [flutter_masked_text](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_masked_text), that does exactly what you want. After adding the package you just have to create a mask controller like this:

```
var controller = new MaskedTextController(mask: '000.000.000-00');
```

And use it on the textfield like this:

```
return new MaterialApp(
title: 'Flutter Demo',
theme: new ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
),
home: new SafeArea(
    child: new Scaffold(
        body: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
                new TextField(controller: controller,) // <--- inserted here
            ],
        ),
    ),
),
);
```

All this examples are on the package documentation. On your case it would be something like this using the package:

```
var socialsecuritycontroller = new MaskedTextController(mask: '000-00-0000'); 

   TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: 'XXX-XX-XXXX',
    ),
    controller: socialsecuritycontroller ,
    obscureText: true,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
 )
```

Hope i could help :)

Comment: hmm i probably misread your question, your problem is actually the dashes being obscured aswell. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63501546/16030126) answer  has a workaround using text widgets between textfields, it maybe helpful.

Comment: thanks for the thoughts. Yeah, the dashes are the challenge. I followed your link but unfortunately that doesn't match the UX spec. I'm currently coding it manually in the onChange param, which is working out so far, fingers crossed

Comment: I see, best of luck then. Sorry i couldn't be of much help.

Comment: @buttonsrtoys if you share your code, will be helpful for me and others.